# How to embed files to dataflow job using python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a batch BEAM job in Python and then running it with Google Dataflow. I would like to extract some part of my Python code to .json file and embed it to python package - the same way I would do in Java.

I've created `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
include *.json
```

and also added `data_files` entry to `setup.py`:

```
data_files=[
    ('.', ['config.json'])
],
```

When I run both `setup.py sdist` and `setup.py bdist` I confirm that file gets included to package.

Also I have a code that loads json file:

```
CONFIG_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / 'config.json'
with path.open() as fp:
    json.load(fp)
```

When I run the module using DirectRunner, files get's loaded. However, when I try to submit that to DataFlow, it fails as it can't find `config.json`. I added debug logging which traverses the file system and I can see that this file isn't present in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` on worker nodes, where all the required libs are installed.

I've looked through Beam documentation, including this one:https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/ and I can't find a recommended way to package non-python files in a Beam job so they are available on worker nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the catch is to add yet another line to `setup.py`:

```
include_package_data=True,
```

Verified it's working.